# How do I keep the infinite timer that triggers JS function on html page?

Tags: javascript

I need to call a function that updates some JS objects on the page every 2 minutes.
How would I do that?

I created a onload function and a countdown function that refreshes a whole page and therefore  resets the timer until next page refresh, but this is not the way I want it. Is there a way to keep an infinite time loop?

I assume, if I could create a an infinite loop and do something like this:

```
if (currentSeconds%120==0){ 
callFunction();
}
```

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried?

Comment: A google search for `timer`, `javascript`, and `function` gave the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setInterval(callFunction, 120000);
```

read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: That is a `setInterval`, not a `setTimeout`. It _is_ infinite. Set the number a bit smaller and you'll see it repeats.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Although, while thinking, I used setTimeout and called a function that is calling recursively  setTimeout! But interval is better! Thanks!